React Typeahead useState
Old coder/New to React,
I am attempting to use the typeahead to fill in address suggestions as the user starts to type in an address.  I've set everything up as per the React Bootstrap Typeahead example page.  Each time I attempt to autofill I can see the drop down appear with my results, but only for a second.  The page refreshes (due to a data update which is expected React behavior). Unfortunately due to the refresh the drop down disappears. How is this not happening in the example?
Thank you in advance!
My Variables
const [addResult, setAddResult] = useState<Address[]>([]);   

The get Call
const getData = async (query: string) => {
     console.log('// onSearch/getData ');
     setIsLoading(true);

     try {
        
         const result = await getAddressSuggestion(query);
         console.log(result);
        

         console.log('// request made');
        
         if (result) {
           
            // console.log(result);
           
             //REFRESHES HERE AND DROP DOWN DISAPPEARS
             setAddResult(result.suggestions ? result.suggestions : []);
             console.log('// Set addResult');
               return;
         }
        
         setIsLoading(false);

     } catch (e) {
         console.log('Error: ' + e)
     }
 }
 const filterBy = () => true;

The Component
I added z-index because ideally I want it in a modal. The console lines are for understanding what is firing when.
<AsyncTypeahead className="select"
      z-index="1051"
      filterBy={filterBy}
      id={`address_${Date.now()}`}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      labelKey="zipcode"
      minLength={3}
      onSearch={getData}
      options={addResult}
      placeholder="Enter Address..."
      useCache={ false }
      onChange={(v) => {
          if (v.length)
              console.log('// onChange');
          else
              console.log('// onChange NO DATA');
      }}
      onInputChange={text => {
          console.log('// onInputChange')
      }}                  
      renderMenuItemChildren={(option: any, props) => (
          <PanelNoHeader>
              <span key={ option.zipcode}>{option.street_line} {option.secondary} {option.city} {option.state} {option.zipcode}</span>
          </PanelNoHeader>
      )}
  />


Surprisingly received no answer, maybe because it was trivial for seasoned React folks?  Or maybe its just a pain all around.
Solution::
As already expressed, its understood that React (as it implies) is designed to refresh on value changes for anything in state.
In my case everytime the onChange event fired (ie: typing in a new value) the whole screen refreshed and focus was no longer on the input. This created odd behavior for the UX.
Here the fix for me;

Create the entire thing as a component and move all the logic
along with it.
Let it handle its own state management.
This avoids the entire parent refreshing.

Hope this helps the next person.
